# Curious case of slow data rate

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ftp, internet-speed

I have a Netgear router (JNR1010) which supports data rate up to 150 Mbps.

[image]

My laptop is connected with the router and so is my mobile (Redmi 2 Prime, 802.11n).

Now, when I create a FTP Server from my mobile and use it to transfer files from my computer to mobile or vice versa, the speed is limited to only around 4 Mbps (~500 KBps). I don't understand the fact why my speed is so slow.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

150Mbps is the maximum theoretical speed, but that is not really achievable in the real world ... 40-50Mbps is typical on Wireless N assuming both devices are connected at the optimum settings with Wireless N, you did not state your laptop's connection. Also remember that WiFi is a half-duplex protocol, essentially cutting that in half or even a quarter if you going laptop to router to phone and back.

Your numbers do seem a bit low, but you did not give any additional information to give an answer on.

http://www.speedguide.net/faq/what-is-the-actual-real-life-speed-of-wireless-374